# My List<Object> is not being passed correctly as object of my ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

In my Spring Controller I have:

```
List<User> Users = this.userService.UsersList();
mav = new ModelAndView("users");
mav.addObject("Users", Users);
```

When I iterate over `Users` I can see all the attributes values of every element of my list.

This is my .jsp code:

```
<c:forEach items="${Users}" var="usr">
  ${usr}
</c:forEach>
```

This is my users class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_perfil")
  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Perfil perfil;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
  @Column(name="usuario")
    private String usuario;
  @Column(name="contrasenia")
    private String contrasenia;
  @Column(name="correo")
    private String correo;
  @Column(name="telefono")
    private String telefono;
  @Column(name="imagen_perfil")
    private String imagen_perfil;
  @Column(name="intento_fallido")
    private int intento_fallido;
  @Column(name="intranet_id")
    private Integer intranet_id;
  @Column(name="intranet_notaria")
    private Integer intranet_notaria;
  @Column(name="intranet_token_codigo")
    private String intranet_token_codigo;
  @Column(name="intranet_token_fecha")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date intranet_token_fecha;
  @Column(name="tesoreria_token_codigo")
    private String tesoreria_token_codigo;
  @Column(name="tesoreria_token_fecha")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date tesoreria_token_fecha;
  @Column(name="activo")
    private int activo;
  
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public Perfil getPerfil() { return perfil; }
    public void setPerfil(Perfil perfil) { this.perfil = perfil; }

    public String getNombre() { return nombre; }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) { this.nombre = nombre; }

  public String getUsuario() { return usuario; }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) { this.usuario = usuario; }

  public String getContrasenia() { return contrasenia; }
    public void setContrasenia(String contrasenia) { this.contrasenia = contrasenia; }

  public String getCorreo() { return correo; }
    public void setCorreo(String correo) { this.correo = correo; }

  public String getTelefono() { return telefono; }
    public void setTelefono(String telefono) { this.telefono = telefono; }
  
  public String getImagenPerfil() { return imagen_perfil; }
    public void setImagenPerfil(String imagen_perfil) { this.imagen_perfil = imagen_perfil; }

  public int getIntentoFallido() { return intento_fallido; }
    public void setIntentoFallido(int intento_fallido) { this.intento_fallido = intento_fallido; }
  
  public Integer getIntranetId() { return intranet_id; }
    public void setIntranetId(Integer intranet_id) { this.intranet_id = intranet_id; }
  
  public Integer getIntranetNotaria() { return intranet_notaria; }
    public void setIntranetNotaria(Integer intranet_notaria) { this.intranet_notaria = intranet_notaria; }
  
  public String getIntranetTokenCodigo() { return intranet_token_codigo; }
    public void setIntranetTokenCodigo(String intranet_token_codigo) { this.intranet_token_codigo = intranet_token_codigo; }
  
  public Date getIntranetTokenFecha() { return intranet_token_fecha; }
    public void setIntranetTokenFecha(Date intranet_token_fecha) { this.intranet_token_fecha = intranet_token_fecha; }
  
  public String getTesoreriaTokenCodigo() { return tesoreria_token_codigo; }
    public void setTesoreriaTokenCodigo(String tesoreria_token_codigo) { this.tesoreria_token_codigo = tesoreria_token_codigo; }
  
  public Date getTesoreriaTokenFecha() { return tesoreria_token_fecha; }
    public void setTesoreriaTokenFecha(Date tesoreria_token_fecha) { this.tesoreria_token_fecha = tesoreria_token_fecha; }

  public int getActivo() { return activo; }
    public void setActivo(int activo) { this.activo = activo; }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id:" + id + ", " + "Perfil:" + perfil.getNombre() + ", " + "Id_Perfil:" + perfil.getId() + ", " + "Nombre:" + nombre + ", " + "Usuario:" + usuario + ", " + "Correo:" + correo + ", " + "Teléfono:" + telefono + ", " + "Image_Perfil:" + imagen_perfil + ", " + "Intranet_Id:" + intranet_id + ", " + "Intranet_Notaria:" + intranet_notaria + ", " + "Activo:" + activo;
    }
  
}
```

The problem is that `${usr}` is only displaying some of my attributes, but not all! I need to display all the attributes in my jsp.

Comment: I'd guess that's because the default `toString()` method only displays those attributes.  You'll need to modify the default `toString()` in the source code, or make a new class that does display what you want when `toString()` is called.  (Or just print out the attributes you want manually in the JSP loop.)

Comment: P.S. Java naming conventions are that local variables should start with a lower case letter.  So `Users` should be `users`.  It really help to stick to these conventions when you need to have other folks (like us) read and understand your code.

Comment: Your comment and also your advice guided me a lot. You made me see things I did not know and realize that my question was not the right one for my problem. When I iterate over the list of objects in the .jsp file, I cannot access all the class attributes with this notation ```${usr.id}``` or ```${usr.name}```.

Comment: We will need to see the source file for `User` to know what to do next.  Which properties from that class do you want to display?

Comment: All of them, I update my post :(

Comment: The ones that are not working are: ```imagen_perfil, intento_fallido, intranet_id, intranet_notaria, intranet_token_codigo, intranet_token_fecha, tesoreria_token_codigo, tesoreria_token_fecha``` and all of them can be null on DB.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using camelCase notation if you are not doing so. For example instead of `${usr.imagen_perfil}` use `${usr.imagenPerfil}`. I think it will be expecting to use the object getters `getImagenPerfil()`.

Comment: Yes!!!!! That was the real problem! I decided to call my getter ```getImagen_perfil``` then I could retrieve my information correctly. Omg! Thats was so difficult. Thanks man!